# C# and Arduino problem with serial port

Tags: serial

I would like to establish a communication between my C# program and my Arduino Duemilanove. I tried lot of different tutorials, but none of them were the same, and I'm a little bit confused.

Actually my code is:

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace InterfaceArduinoWindowsFOrm {
  public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
      serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";
      serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
      serialPort1.Open();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    }

    private void tabPage2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    }

    private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e) {
    }

    private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
      Console.WriteLine("test");
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      serialPort1.Write("5");
      Console.WriteLine(serialPort1.IsOpen);
    }
  }
}
```

Arduino:

```
/* Sweep
  by BARRAGAN <http://barraganstudio.com>
  This example code is in the public domain.
  modified 8 Nov 2013
  by Scott Fitzgerald
  http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sweep
*/

#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // Create servo object to control a servo.
// Twelve servo objects can be created on most boards.
int pos = 0;
int message = 0; // This will hold one byte of the serial message
                 // variable to store the servo position.

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.attach(9);  // Attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {

    // Check to see if there is a new message
    message = Serial.read();

    // Put the serial input into the message
    Serial.print(message);

    if (message == '5') {
      Serial.print("test");
      for(pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) {
        // Goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
        // in steps of 1 degree

        myservo.write(pos);
        // Tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'

        delay(15);
        // Waits 15 ms for the servo to reach the position
      }

      for(pos = 180; pos>=0; pos-=1) {
        // Goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees

        myservo.write(pos);
        // Tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'

        delay(15);
        // Waits 15 ms for the servo to reach the position
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, when I click my button, nothing happens, but obviously if I remove the `if` statement, the servo motor code works.

Comment: Did you make sure that the C# button event is fired, and that the Serial connection is established properly? Also, what happens if you open the Arduino COM terminal and press 5?

Comment: Hum yea , i tested with some console writte and Button work , what do you mean by : press 5?

Comment: I mean that, in your C# code, you just send "5" to the serial port. As part of the debugging - pin pointing where the problem lays - did you use the Arduino Serial console to send "5" the same way you send it from C#, and made sure it works there? Because if sending "5" from the Serial console in the Arduino IDE doesn't work, the C# way won't work either.

Comment: I follow lot of tutoriel covering this , the code is really similar as mine , but , when I try to use the serial monitor , and I try to fire button event , it say that Com3 is already in use and unauthorized ... 5 is only a message id to call the arduino IF statement ....

Comment: Yes, I get that 5 is the trigger. What I'm trying to understand is whether that trigger works or not. You cannot use Arduino IDE Serial Monitor while running your C# code since the Arduino COM port can interface only one serial port at a time. Try using the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor after closing the C# serial port and not in parallel to it.

Comment: Ok , but how to make sure if my arduino trigger is activated

Comment: As I suggested; do not run the C# app, only use the Arduino IDE Serial Console to send '5' and examine the results.

Comment: A ok ! But how to send 5 from serial monitor , just input 5 on the input text ?

Comment: Yes. If you do that, do you get the desired result?

Comment: I can confirm you this in arround 1 hour

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending from the Arduino the received serial data back to the C# application (`Serial.print(message);`), I would advise to check what you receive on the C# side.
Register to the DataReceived event of the SerialPort as so:

```
serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
```

And add an event handler:

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort port = (SerialPort)sender;
    string data= port.ReadExisting();
    // check here what data you received, if any
}
```

This way you could confirm that the Arduino gets the data properly from the C# side to begin with. Next step would be to understand if this **if** statement treats the data properly:

```
if (message == '5')
```

But starting from examination of what you get from the C# side will help you decide where exactly is the problem.

Comment: EDIT : NeverMind I missundarstood your post i'm sorry, But i acctualy don't understand your answer, do you mean that I try to send from Arduino to C# because, Me I want to do the opposite...

Comment: Yes, I mean that you try send from Arduino to C# (you are already doing that) and see what you get. This will help you understand where is the problem.

Comment: Ok so i Will try if i understand to directly send from arduino to c#

Comment: You are already doing it... the line "Serial.print(message);" sending the message back to the C# code. Just see what you get from the C# side as I explained.

Comment: Hooo yea it was a test code , but I forget to read from C# I'm sorry if I didn't understand but it's because I forget this line ...

Comment: any progress with this?

Comment: Tomorow , i CAN continue working on this ,i had´nt GOT the time until now , tomorrow I can tell you if it's working

Comment: Ok , i test right now what you said about serialDataReceivedEvent with a  DataReceivedHandler method : { /---what you write --/ Console.WriteLine("received data "+ data); }  I connected the arduino with USB cable and launched the C# program , but obviously I don't compile my program at the same time as it say that COM3 port is already in use ... So, I received some data but it seems encrypted , for example : "Z?" Or "J?"   I will try other message stay tuned,      Edit : apparently message seems to work , yea. I successful receive data from my arduino to my C# program ! Now lt go arduino part!